# Regex for checking date format in perl

Tags: regex, perl, date

I have a problem with creating regex for checking date which looks like this:

## 2017-07-12 14:41:56.784

I need to create it in perl but it's completly new for me. Any suggestions how to write it and how to use it with "IF" condition ?

Comment: First please start reading [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What have you tried til now?

Comment: @ssr1012: Your link to the TT2 documentation doesn't seem particularly useful in this case. And the Tutorials Point Perl tutorial is well-known to be terrible (for example, in this case, it gets through a whole page about dates and times without once mentioning Time::Piece or DateTime). Please don't link to it.

Comment: @ssr1012: And yet, a week later those links are still there :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the module [`Regexp::Common::time`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Common::time).

```
use Regexp::Common qw(time);                           
my $str = "2017-07-12 14:41:56.784";                   
print "Time Gentlemen" if $str =~ m/^$RE{time}{iso}\z/ ;
```

The [`Regexp::Common`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Common) modules make using regular expressions for all kinds of things much easier and potentially less error prone. It *is* helpful to bear in mind JWZ's infamous [*caveat*](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Jamie_Zawinski) regarding regular expressions - but using perl and `Regexp::Common` allows one to keep calm and carry on.

Comment: Regexp::Common regexes are not anchored; you should make it `m/^$RE{time}{iso}\z/`

Comment: Good point - changed  the answer to reflect your comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No need to include any module,
To match any **datetime** like this: `2017-07-12 14:41:56.784`

For example `"2017-07-12 14:41:56.784"`

```
$str="2017-07-12 14:41:56.784"; 
if($str =~ /[1-9]{1}[0-9]{3}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{3}/)
{
    print "match found";
}
```